# Print all contiguous subarray

Tags: python, recursion, sub-array

I want to write a recursive function to add all of the contiguous subarrays in a list.
The function works but there is some duplication. I wanted to know if there is a way to avoid this.

```py
def numSubArray(array, result):
    if len(array) == 0:
        return []
    result.append(array)
    numSubArray(array[1:], result)
    numSubArray(array[:-1], result)
    return result
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Doing both of Modifying `result`(It is called **side effect**) and returning `result` is not a good design of function. Like `sorted` and `list.sort`, it is usual to choice one of them.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning/logic behind this function?

Answer (score 1):

#### solution 1. brute-force recursion and remove duplicates

You can eliminate duplications using `set`.
But you cannot make `set` of `list`s since `list` is not hashable.
And for efficiency, you can gather index-pairs first, and then slice:

```py
def num_sub_array(array):
    return [
        array[i:j] for i, j in build_pair_set(0, len(array))
    ]


def build_pair_set(start: int, end: int) -> set:
    return set() if start == end else (
        {(start, end)}
        | build_pair_set(start + 1, end)
        | build_pair_set(start, end - 1)
    )


print(sorted(num_sub_array([1, 2, 3, 4])))
```

output:

```py
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]
```

---

#### solution 2. recursion without redundancy

```py
def num_sub_array(array):
    if not array:
        return []
    return [array[i:] for i in range(len(array))] + num_sub_array(array[:-1])


print(sorted(num_sub_array([1, 2, 3, 4])))
```

output:

```py
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]
```

---

Actually, solution 2's `num_sub_array` has a tail recursion. So you can change it to loop.

#### Solution 3. Loop

```py
def num_sub_array(array):
    return [
        array[i:j]
        for i in range(len(array))
        for j in range(i + 1, len(array) + 1)
    ]


print(sorted(num_sub_array([1, 2, 3, 4])))
```

output:

```py
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]
```

---

I used `sorted` for comparing two methods. It is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to produce the following to produce all subsequences of a non-empty `array`:

1. `array` (that is, all subsequences that include *both* the first and last items in `array`)
2. all subsequences of `array[1:]` (that is, all subsequences that do *not* include the first item in `array`
3. all subsequences of `array[:-1]` (that is, all subsequences that do *not* include the last item in `array`

So the source of the duplication is clear: any subsequence that has neither the first nor the last item in `array` will be counted twice (in any given call, meaning the longer `array` is, the more copies you can get).

The solution, hopefully, is also clear; remove #1 (it will be covered by what follows) and either

- replace #3 will all subsequences that *do* include the first item in `array`, or
- replace #2 with all subsequences that *do* include the last item in `array`

Comment: I dont understand the #1 and for the #2/#3 I need to remplace the first or the second recursive call by     `numSubArray(array[1:-1], result)` ?

Comment: No; see edit about #1.  And `numSubArray` does not make the guarantee that these need.

Comment: Sorry , I really dont get how do I need to change my code/vision of the algorithm ?

Answer (score 0):

You have an array as input and you want to return a list with all the values in this array, preferably using a recursive function?

I think you want this:

```
new_list = []
def array_to_list(arr): 
     for i in arr: 
         if isinstance(i,list) or isinstance(i,array.array): 
             array_to_list(arr) 
         else: 
             new_list.append(i)
a = arr.array('d',  [1.1, 3.5, 4.5])
array_to_list(a)
print(new_list)
```

The last line will print your listed array!

Comment: How about `isinstance(i, list)` instead of `type(i)==list`?

Answer (score 0):

**Iterative Approach: using generator function**

you can also use generator to yield all possible continuous subarray:

```
from typing import List


def brute_force(nums: List[int]) -> int:
    i = j = 0
    while j <= len(nums) and i <= len(nums):
        yield nums[i:j+1]
        j += 1
        if j == len(nums):
            i += 1
            j = I

list(brute_force([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```